# WPF: Check if two ModelVisual3Ds are mostly overlapping

Tags: wpf, collision-detection, intersection, hittest, modelvisual3d

I have a question regarding WPF programming, and it's with regards to whether we can check if a certain percentage of a shape is intersecting/overlapping with another shape. My intention is to create a minigame where there will be a model (e.g. a *cube*), and the app will apply a random `Transform` to it. The user then needs to manually rotate and resize the model using given controls, and fit it into (roughly) the randomly `Transform`-ed cube.

Is there any method/algorithm I can apply for two `ModelVisual3D`s within the same `Viewport3D`? It would be ideal if the method can return a percentage (e.g. 0.8, 0.9), so that I can tweak it to accept only if the percentage is above a certain level.

Many thanks!